# Trying to use onEdit to autofill timeline of a Gantt Chart

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create an apps script to autofill a gantt chart when the sheet is edited, but having trouble.

[Here is a link to the spreadsheet if it helps.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Iy7tDN3-W5H2335qo7CCZQn1csm-JhzGQ1amU37jlHk/edit?usp=sharing)

```
function ganttChart()
{
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ganttSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Gantt Chart");
  var headerRow = ss.ganttSheet.getRange('headerRow').getRow();
  var lastRow = ss.ganttSheet.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = ss.ganttSheet.getLastColumn();
  var firstTask = headerRow + 1
  var taskRoleCol = ss.ganttSheet.getRange('taskRole').getColumn();
  //I'm not sure if I need to do the below RoleCol if I already have a named range -- this will return an integer which is the column #
  var roleCol = ss.getSheetByName("Roles").getRange('Roles').getColumn();
  var taskCol = ss.ganttSheet.getRange('taskNames').getColumn();
  var startWeekRow = ss.ganttSheet.getRange('startWeek').getRow();
  var expDurationCol = ss.ganttSheet.getRange('expDuration').getColumn();

  //set the requirements for the edit trigger -- not sure what these would be
  //if (e.range)
  //{
    for (var i = firstTask; i < lastRow; i++)
    {
      var currentTask = ss.ganttSheet.getRange(i, taskCol).getValue();
      var currentStartWeek = ss.ganttSheet.getRange(i, startWeekCol).getValue();
      var currentTaskExpDuration = ss.ganttSheet.getRange(i,expDurationCol).getValue();
      var currentTaskRole = ss.ganttSheet.getRange(i,taskRoleCol).getValue();

      if (currentTask != null)
      {
        if (currentStartWeek != null)
        {
          //for loop to identify the column that matches the start week #
          for (var j = 0; j < lastCol; j++)
          {
            
            var checkWeek = ss.ganttSheet.getRange(startWeekRow, j).getValue();

            if (checkWeek == currentStartWeek)
            {
              
              //identify the range
              var taskTimeRange = ss.ganttSheet.getRange(i,j - 1,(currentTaskExpDuration*2 +1), 1);
              //for loop get the background color based on role
              for (var k = 0; k < lastRow; k++)
              {
                var checkRole = ss.ganttSheet.getRange(k, roleCol).getValue();
                //if role value matches the currentTaskRole
                if (checkRole == currentTaskRole)
                {
                  
                  var roleColor = ss.ganttSheet.getRange(k, roleCol).getBackground();
                  //reformat the range based on duration
                  taskTimeRange.setBackground(roleColor);

                }
                  
              }
              
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  //}
}
```

I took off the "onEdit" to try and get the program to work on run, but I'm still getting a "cannot read properties of undefined" error.

What should happen is:

- when a user edits the "Gantt Chart" sheet
- the program changes the background color in the corresponding range to indicate the weeks a task is being worked on, based on the start week and calculated duration
- the background color should correspond to the task role, based on the colors set in the "Roles" sheet
- [If the above isn't clear, here is a link to a video where I try to explain what the program should do](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19SborhMGrlIJvpEzmeZFfQ0c7rOn9UkV/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the sample input and output situations you expect?

Comment: Hi. Would you please edit your question to provide the complete text of the error. Also, though you have provided your spreadsheet, you can/should not use that as a basis to avoid an explanation of the layout of your spreadsheet, relevant sheets and other information. In addition, the use of `onEdit` to trigger an autofill for a Gantt chart is NOT obvious. Would you please edit your question to provide the information mentioned and also explain your scenario and EXACTLY what you are trying to with your code.

Comment: I **highly recommend** you **do not** give edit access to everybody. This may result in some (not so nice) people sabotaging your document. I’ve gone ahead and removed the edit access, so you don’t need to worry.

Comment: @Fastnlight Thank you for doing that. I'm not sure why I gave edit access. Slip of the mind probably.

Comment: I added a video explanation of how the sheet should function. I hope that helps clear it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question relates to `onEdit` but the trigger is, at this point of development of the script, irrelevant, since the script is littered with syntax errors.

Even so, I suggest that the trigger is irrelevant in any event. The script can/should be triggered when the data has been populated. This trigger can be done manually, or (perhaps) via a [menu option](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu).

---

`getRange()`, getLastRow() and `getLastColumn` are [sheet-based methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#methods).

**Incorrect**

```
var headerRow = ss.ganttSheet.getRange('headerRow').getRow()
var lastRow = ss.ganttSheet.getLastRow()
var lastCol = ss.ganttSheet.getLastColumn()
```

**Correct**

```
var headerRow = ganttSheet.getRange('headerRow').getRow()
var lastRow = ganttSheet.getLastRow()
var lastCol = ganttSheet.getLastColumn()
```

**Other**
`startWeekCol` is not defined
`for (var j = 0; j < lastCol; j++)`

- "j" substitutes for the column number, but a value of 0 is invalid

`var taskTimeRange = ganttSheet.getRange(i,j - 1,(currentTaskExpDuration*2 +1), 1)`

- when "j" is 1, "j-1" resolves to 0 (zero) which is invalid

`for (var k = 0; k < lastRow; k++)`

- "k" substitutes for the row number, but a value of 0 is invalid

Comment: Thank you. I've mostly been coding in C up to now and slowly transitioning to JS, so thank you for the corrections on my syntax. I didn't think I was that far off, but seems I need to do a little more studying.

Comment: The distinction between the methods that are "spreadsheet", "sheet" and "range"  can be confusing ;) BTW, since you are using named ranges, there's also a method `getRangeByName()` [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangebynamename) that could be handy.